# error: package android.view does not exist

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, mobile-application

I am getting this error in view bindings file generated by Android studio. I have added

```
buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
```

to the app build.gradle file.

Comment: Does not have enough information to investigate the issue. It would be helpful if you can share the full error log?

Comment: i am getting only this much error. The file view bindings file which are generated when you compile the code are showing the android.view package does not exist.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Updating the android studio to the latest version fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 17):

In your build.gradle(:app) file,

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

Try changing the java version.
I got the same error when using VERSION_11 but the VERSION_1_8 fixed the issue.

Comment: what if someone must use JDK11 for other dependency issues?

Answer (score 4):

Android Studio don' t update Gradle to version 7.
Open project Structure, you can find in File, set in Project:
Android Gradle Plugin Version: 7.0.0
and
Gradle Version: 7.0.2
Compile now and all will work fine.